# How to find divergent coordinates?

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a list of coordinates (longitude and latitude) in a csv-file. The coordinates are representing a store. There are almost a hundred files over stores, one per country. But some coordinates are wrong (Manually written in by employees).

There are about 100 stores (in average) in each country. 
I could sent the coordinates to the google api to check if it is the same country as the rest but the google maps api will only recieved 2500 request for free.

How could I code a method that will just test some divergent coordinates instead of every coordinate?

Here we have a example of coordinates of stores in france. But one coordinate is located in Ghana.

```
latitude    longitude
42,82377    0,316521
46,180742   6,7042473
45,0144927  6,1242264
42,6281     9,4206
46,0259861  6,6388244
47,9622395  1,8441825
5,623027    -1,043182
44.773491   6.03283
48,2814547  7,4579305
50.726231   1.60238
45,751175   3,110678
46,1875023   5.2071938
44,944816   4,841903
45,1484023  5,7223511
44,556944   4,749496
45,467654   4,352633
45,564601   5,917781
45,556935   5,971688
47,312494   5,117044
45,93813    6,090965
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe making an average value of coordinates :

```
$average = array('latitude' => 0, 'longitude' => 0);
// determine the total of coordinates values
foreach($coordinates as $coord){
    $average['latitude'] += $coord['latitude'];
    $average['longitude'] += $coord['longitude'];
}

// Divide by the number of coordinates to get an average value of the lat/long
$average['latitude'] /= count($coordinates);
$average['longitude'] /= count($coordinates);

// max distance to considere the measure is bad
$maxDistance = 5.0;  // YOU SHOULD CONFIGURE THIS VARIABLE

// then, we determinate strangers :p
$strangers = array();
foreach($coordinates as $coord){
    if($coord['latitude'] > $average['latitude'] + $maxDistance 
       OR $coord['latitude'] < $average['latitude'] - $maxDistance
       OR $coord['longitude'] > $average['longitude'] + $maxDistance
       OR $coord['longitude'] < $average['longitude'] - $maxDistance){
            $strangers[] = $coord;
    }
}

// you get your list, and you can use it
foreach($strangers as $strange){
   echo $strange['latitude'] . " : " . $strange['longitude'];
}
```

I think there are many algorithmes outhere which are better than this one by the way...